# Из Java в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, java, android

У меня есть программа, написанная на Java (для Android). Теперь требуется написать аналогичную для iOS. В моей программе модель достаточно хорошо отделена от UI и вся эта логика в iOS-программе будет такой же. Я начал переписывать всё это руками, но теперь понимаю, что это займет слишком много времени. Тем более когда будут появляться ошибки, надо будет вносить одни и те же изменения в оба приложения.

Можно ли как-то по-быстрому сгенерировать Objectve-C код из Java кода?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я бы не пытался идти таким путем. Все таки, у андроида и айОС разные модели поведения. Например, приложение на андроиде всегда должно быть готовым к тому, что его закроют, а вот под айОС приложению дается какое то время на завершение работы. Наличие-отсутсвие приложений в фоне, наличие уборщика мусора и необходимость следить за ресурсами.
Поэтому, все таки правильнее просто переписать.
Но есть один обходной путь. Андроид позволяет писать часть приложения на с/с++ (ndk, хотя это и не рекомендуется), для айОС, насколько мне известно, тоже можно на с писать. Поэтому,  графическую часть пишем для каждой платформы свою, а сложную логику - просто перекомпилируем.

Answer (score 3):

Можешь переписать логику на С++, и тогда на Obj-C/Java останется только UI.
А сконвертить, это конечно что-то из ряда фантастики (=

Answer (score 0):

Лучше перепишите с Java Android на любой из фреймворков, типа `PhoneGap`, `Appcelerator Titanium`, `Rhodes`, `RhoSync`, etc. 
И сможете портировать не только на iOS, но и на `Symbian`, `Blackberry` и другие.

Comment: Ни когда не прислушивайтесь к советам призывающим вас использовать PhoneGap!!! Зачем заставлять конечного пользователя мучатся видя ваш убогий дизайн и заторможенность в работе!

Comment: согласен. Фреймворки дерьмо (по крайней мере для приложений). Сам изучал Appcelerator и понял какое это г. Для отзывчивого UX нужно писать только нативные приложения. 
2 vanyamelikov : могли бы посмотреть что комментарию больше 2 лет